# iBeaconを使用して、NCMBのpush通知をしたい

Tags: monaca, push-notification, ibeacon

こんにちは。JavaScriptを使って、Beacon検知したらPush通知を送信したいのですが
Beacon検知してもNCMBへPush通知が送信できません。以下ソース（一部抜粋）です。
何かいいサンプルがありますでしょうか？
（本当はNearになったらPush通知を送信したいです）
よろしくお願いいたします。

```
delegate.didRangeBeaconsInRegion = function (pluginResult) {
    var reg = pluginResult.region;
    var beac = pluginResult.beacons;
    for (i = 0; i < beac.length; i = i +1) {
        if (beac[i] != null) {
            console.log(beac[i].proximity);
            NCMB.Push.send(
            {
              "deliveryTime": {"__type": "Date", "iso": "2013-09-31T17:41:09.106Z"},
              "immediateDeliveryFlag": true,
              "target": ['ios'],
              "message": "Hello! World!!",
              "dialog": true,
              "richUrl": "http://www.nifty.com"
            }, 
            {
              success: function() {
                console.log('success');
                // 成功
              },
              error: function(error) {
                // エラー
                console.log('Failed');
              }
            });
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

私も、ibeaconを最近始めたのですが、テストする度にビルドしなきゃいけないのが面倒ですよね。。。
丁度、私もNear圏内になったらNCMBのデータストアにレコードを追加するような方法を考えていました。
https://github.com/divineprog/evo-demos/blob/master/Demos2014/iBeaconDemo/app.js
このページの119行目とか参考になりませんか？
進展があったら是非どんなコードにしたか教えてください。

Comment: お返事ありがとうございます。
iBeacon 難しいですね。
私も頂いたURLを参考にしておりました。

ちなみに
NCMB.Push.send の前に
NCMB.initialize(APIキー , クライアントキー）を入れたら以下のエラーです。

error in success callbackId: LocationManager888871481 : TypeError: undefiened is not a function(evaluating 'NCMB.initialize')

エラー解析してみます

Answer (score 1):

解決できました。
原因）
jsフォルダの中のncmb-latest.min.js ファイルがなかったことです。Cordovaプラグインの追加でNifty MB を追加すると生成されるファイルのようです。
以下サンプルソースです。（一部抜粋）

```
delegate.didRangeBeaconsInRegion = function (pluginResult) {
    var reg = pluginResult.region;
    var beac = pluginResult.beacons;
    for (i = 0; i < beac.length; i = i +1) {
        if (beac[i] != null) {
            console.log(beac[i].proximity);
            NCMB.initialize("APIキー, "クライアントキー");
            NCMB.Push.send(
            {
                "immediateDeliveryFlag": true,
                "target": ['ios'],
                "message": "Hello! Tony!!",
                "richUrl": "http://www.nifty.com",
            }, 
            {
              success: function() {
                console.log('success');
                // 成功
              },
              error: function(error) {
                // エラー
                console.log('Failed');
              }
            });
        }
    }
};
```